# Law of large numbers with weights

Tags: probability-theory

Let $X_1 , X_2 , ...$ be an iid sequence with mean 0 and finite variance. Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence of non-random real numbers. Under what conditions on $(a_n)$ do the weighted means $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^n a_j X_j$ converge almost surely to 0?

The law of large numbers tells us that this will be the case if $a_j = 1$ for each $j$. By scaling the same is true if each $a_j$ is equal to the same constant $c$. Furthermore, if $c \leq a_j \leq C$ for each $j$, then we have

$$   \frac{c}{n} \sum_{j=1}^n a_j X_j   \leq \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^n a_j X_j \leq \frac{C}{n} \sum_{j=1}^n a_j X_j $$

and the left and right sides tend to 0 a.s. So, the statement is true if the $a_j$'s all belong to some finite interval. However, it strikes me as unlikely to be true if the $a_j$'s grow too rapidly. So, I am looking for some minimal condition under which the convergence does hold. Does anyone know of one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many versions of the strong law of large numbers for sequences of random variables that are independent but not identically distributed.

One version is listed on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers#Strong_law) as "Kolmogorov's strong law": If $Y_k$ are independent and $\sum_k \frac{1}{k^2} \operatorname{Var}(Y_k) < \infty$, then $\bar{Y}_n - E \bar{Y}_n \to 0$ almost surely.

Taking $Y_k = a_k X_k$, where $X_k$ are iid with mean zero and finite variance, this says that if $\sum_k a_k^2 / k^2 < \infty$, then $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n a_k X_k \to 0$ almost surely.

For example, $a_k = k^{0.4999}$ would work.

Comment: What is $\bar{Y}_n$ in your answer?  Is it $\bar{Y}_n  = \frac{1}{n} \sum_k Y_k$?  What if we are interested in  $\sum_k w_k X_k$?  Do we just re-define $w_k \to n w_k$ and apply this law?

Comment: @Confounded: Yes, same notation as in the Wikipedia link.  This notation is very common.

Comment: PS.  In my comment above, $w_k$ are such that $\sum_k w_k = 1$.  Thank you

Comment: @Confounded: No, that's really a separate question.  You generally need different (though somewhat related) techniques to handle infinite sums like $\sum_{k=1}^\infty Y_k$ versus sequences of normalized finite sums like $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n Y_k$.  Kronecker's lemma can help reduce the latter to the former, but that doesn't help you.

Comment: For series like $\sum_k w_k X_k$, look up Kolmogorov's three-series theorem.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and suggestions. However, I am not sure if we fully understood each other. If in the "vanilla" SLLN we define $w_k = \frac{1}{n}$ so that $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n X_k = \sum_{k=1}^n w_k X_k$, we also have $\sum_{k=1}^n w_k = 1$. What I was asking is if the SLLN still holds if these weights $w_k$ are different for each $X_k$.  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

As a step towards answering this, consider var$(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^na_iX_i)$. 
This suggests that convergence happens if the $\ell_2$ norm of $(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ grows no faster than $\sqrt{n}$.

It is not obvious to me whether a weaker condition is possible.